# Mysql left join count if table is no null

Tags: mysql, sql

im making a lefjoin consult in mysql like this

```
    SELECT A.*,B.*,C.*,D.* 
    from TableA A 
    left join TableB B on A.id=B.id
    left join TableC C on A.id=C.id
    left join TableD D on A.id=D.id
    where
//some condition
//group by
//order by
```

The final result is a array unidimensional, but some values no have data them for example i have some values `B.Value1: null`, `C.Value1: null`, `B.Value2: null` , etc.

I'm looking for, it is to count only tables with data, Eq.

- B table is blank for `id=20`  so the result for this id should be 3(A,C and D)
- C,D table is blank for `id=22`  so the result for this id should be 2(A and B)

**Note :**

- if 1 value in a table is null them the table no have data for this id
- table A always have data

Comment: I guess you misunderstand the concept of mysql query statement and result. So when you query any statement the result will always have the same number of columns. So if your expectations: *B table is blank for id=20 so the result for this id should be 3(A,C and D)* means you expect that for some records in your result set will have 3 columns, and some of records 4 columns -and some records return 2 columns - your expectations are absolutely wrong. you can't do that with any sql server  (mysql, sql, oracle, postgres). Never result set will include different number of columns for different rows.

Comment: You could "emulate" this behavior by concatenating results in a single column (the basic MySQL concat function ignores null values) but it's dodgy.

Comment: Use a `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @EternalHour type of join change nothing in this case.

Comment: @Alex I'm not talking about the number of rows that have the query, because always i get the same number of rows, I want to know, what table has data.

Comment: I didn't talk about number of rows, I've told about number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but I am assuming you want to get a result with 2 columns. In the first column you want the id which is present in A and in the second column you want the number of tables that ID appears in. if so this should work...

```
﻿﻿SELECT id, count(*) as num 
FROM (
    SELECT A.id FROM TableA A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.id FROM TableB B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.id FROM TableC C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.id FROM TableD D
) mytables
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a query that uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select id, count(distinct which) as NumTablesWithValue
from ((select id, value, 'a' as which from tableA) union all
      (select id, value, 'b' from tableb) union all
      (select id, value, 'c' from tablec) union all
      (select id, value, 'd' from tabled)
     ) i
group by id;
```